# When is get_currentuserinfo() needed?

Tags: hooks, actions

I know you usually call it inside functions after `global $current_user`, but sometimes it works whether you have it or not.

So what are the conditions where is it needed?

Sample code:

```
function plugin_admin_init(){
    global $current_user;

    // Make sure global is set, if not set it.
    get_currentuserinfo();
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use [`wp_get_current_user()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user), no globals:

```
function plugin_admin_init() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
}
```